# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add') while adding a class through angular's renderer2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-renderer2

Here's my code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]',
})

export class DropdownDirective {
  isClassApplied: boolean;
  @Input('appDropdown') className: string;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.isClassApplied = false;
  }

    @HostListener('click') onClickAddClass() {
        if (!this.isClassApplied) {
            this.isClassApplied = true;
            this.renderer.addClass(this.elRef, this.className);
        } else {
            this.isClassApplied = false;
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.elRef, this.className);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the html: [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/shubhRepository/pen/mdjNjZZ)

It is giving me an error when trying to add a class on the `elRef`.
Can anyone please tell me what's wrong in this.

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is i haven't given the correct argument to `addClass` function. I must have to pass the element on which the directive sits on. And that should be found under the `nativeElement` of the ElementRef.

So the code look like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]',
})

export class DropdownDirective {
  isClassApplied: boolean;
  @Input('appDropdown') className: string;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.isClassApplied = false;
  }

    @HostListener('click') onClickAddClass() {
        if (!this.isClassApplied) {
            this.isClassApplied = true;
            this.renderer.addClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, this.className);
        } else {
            this.isClassApplied = false;
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, this.className);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the error is exactly, but notice that the input in your directives should be without the [bindingPropertyName](https://angular.io/api/core/Input#bindingPropertyName), like that:

`@Input() appDropdown: string;`

Then in your component you can write:

```
<div [appDropdown]="class_name"></div>
```

[source](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

Comment: Error is exactly what's in the title, but this solution doesn't work error persists anyways. Can you suggest any other solution? Thanks.

Comment: Here's is the image of an error: https://ibb.co/x8Ntb93

Answer (score 0):

It seems the DOM element is missing when the directive tries to add a class name. This issue may arise when the directive appDropDown is inside *ngIf structural directive.
Trying using [hidden] property or use css opacity property in case you are using ngIf.

Comment: Here's the html of it: https://codepen.io/shubhRepository/pen/mdjNjZZ. Btw i don't have any structural directives.

Comment: The codepen which you share doesn't seem to replicate the issue, could you share it in stackblitz?